# Hide Duplicate Cells in Table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide duplicated cells in a **table**. See Image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Hpa.jpg

Result(I manualy hide the NotebookNames, thats what my comment was about)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkWhz.jpg

In the first column we got "Image Names", I want to hide(paint the cell white) the duplicates, only leaving the first "duplicate" up.
In the second column there is "Image Version", I want to hide duplicates here also, but dependent on column "Image Names". So if there is 2 times "Image S400" + Version 1.3, hide the 2nd "Image Names" + "Image Version".

I am trying this, with Conditional Formatting right now, but I am kinda sure this is not the way.

Is this possible with Conditional Formatting? Or do I have to tackle this with VBA?

Greetings and a nice week

Declade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want hide cells or Rows, if your choice is the 2th you can use this sub that read all rows into your table and if the Image Name and Image Version of the current row is the some of the previous row the current row will be hidden

```
    Sub HideDoubleRst()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    Dim UR As Long, X As Long
    Dim MyCol As Integer    
    MyCol = Range("A:A").Column
    UR = Cells(Rows.Count, MyCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For X = 2 To UR
        If Cells(X, MyCol) = Cells(X - 1, MyCol) And Cells(X, MyCol + 1) = Cells(X - 1, MyCol + 1) Then
        Rows(X).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next X
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = true
    End Sub
Or if you want only hide the 2 cells you can change the backgroundcolor and thee fontcolor to white

```
Sub ColorDoubleRst()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim UR As Long, X As Long
    Dim MyCol As Integer

    MyCol = Range("A:A").Column
    UR = Cells(Rows.Count, MyCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For X = 2 To UR
    If Cells(X, "A") = Cells(X - 1, "A") Then
        Cells(X, "A").Select
        With Selection.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        End With
        With Selection.Interior
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        End With
        If Cells(X, "B") = Cells(X - 1, "B") Then
            Cells(X, "B").Select
            With Selection.Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            End With
            With Selection.Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            End With

            If Cells(X, "F") = Cells(X - 1, "F") Then
                Cells(X, "F").Select
                With Selection.Font
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                End With
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next X
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to hide just the 2 cells. In A2 we have Image S400 and in B2 1.3. Now I just want to hide the cells A3 and B3 in this case, because they are the same as above. When for example "Image Name" is Image S400 but "Image Version" is 1.4 for example then only hide the cell "Image Name"

Comment: @Declare, I add the sub ColorDoubleRst and I think is that you want

Comment: this works awesome, thank you. But I got 1 last question, if I want to add another column to check in there, where would I do that? For example NotebookName Column F?

Comment: @Declade, if the answer right, please mark it. add one or more condition is not problem but I've to know what is the final result, update you img

Comment: @Declade, you Hided the cell F6, it's equal to F5 but change the ImageVersion from 1.1 to 2.1, it's correct?!?!? then the column NothebookName it's released from first 2 columns??

Comment: Ah you are right my bad... ofcourse it's not released from ImageName and ImageVersion, will upload a new screenshot

Comment: @Declade, I add the Notebook Name control. If you see I change the cell reference from "mycol +1" to the corresponding column "B", I think is more easy for you if you have to add more control, now you have the instruments to do